# Zero records for different when conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, left-join

How do i display zero record in sqlserver if i dont find anything

```
select count(*) as[count],
case when status=0 then 'pending'
when status=1 then 'running'
when status=2 then 'completed'
end as status
from Queue where ID='APP'
group by status
```

what i want is if there is no record for status=0, how should i display 0 in the result also for other status as well. I need something like pending=0,running=0 and completed=0 if no rows found for respective status.
I tried something like below, but that does not suit my need. Any Idea?

```
if exists (myselect query)
    select 1
else
    select 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `values()` and a `left join`:

```
select s.descr, count(q.id) cnt
from (values (0, 'pending'), (1, 'running'), (2, 'completed')) s(status, descr)
left join queue q on q.status = s.status and q.id = 'APP'
group by s.descr
```

This generates one row per status, with the count of rows in such status in table `queue`.

Comment: may i know what is descr?

Comment: @sea29ram: that would be the *description* of the status.